# alguien me indica el por que se me descarga un php al momento de enviar datos por el GET ej: editar.php?id=<?php echo $row[0] ?> donde $row[0]=1

Tags: php, xampp, crud, enlace

[image: me sale el siguiente error al querer enviar variables por el link, hago un crud en una conexion de php y sql server 2018 con ayuda de xamp pero no puedo editar ni eliminar por que no me deja pasar datos por el link, alguien me ayuda por favor?]

me sale el siguiente error al querer enviar variables por el link, hago un crud  en una conexion de php y sql server 2018 con ayuda de xamp pero no puedo editar ni eliminar por que no me deja pasar datos por el link, alguien me ayuda por favor?

```
<table class="table table-hover table-ligth table-success table-sm" border="5" >
                        <thead align="center" >
                            <th>id</th>
                            <th>Pais</th>
                            <th>Editar</th>
                            <th>Eliminar</th>
                        </thead>
                        
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                                $query="select * from PAIS";
                                $res=sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);

                                while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($res)){
                            ?>
                                    <tr align="center">
                                        <td><?=$row[0]?></td>
                                        <td><?=$row[1]?></td>
                                        <td>
                                                <a href="pais_editar.php?id=<?php echo $row[0]?>">
                                                <i style="font-size: 1.1rem; color: rgb(8, 8, 8);" class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i>
                                                </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                                <a href="">
                                                <i style="font-size: 1.1rem; color: rgb(8, 8, 8);" class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    
                                <?php
                                }//while
                                ?>
                        </tbody>
                        
                    </table>
```

Comment: envías datos por `GET`? no debería ser por `POST`

Comment: Buenas men, para poder ayudarte debes mostrar el codigo... sino como sabremos que estas haciendo bien y mal ???

Comment: gracias por la observacion, ya añadi el codigo y como pueden ver en la imagen. cada que preciono el enlace que esta dentro del boton se me descargar el php al que esta dirigido

Answer (score 0):

creo que tendrias que pasarle el id a modificar como parametro, y recogerlo en la pagina pais_editar.php como parametro para mandar la instrucción SQL.

```
 <a href="pais_editar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>">
```